# Node: AWS KMS erasing public key from memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-sdk, amazon-kms

From the docs for the KMS operation `GenerateDataKey` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/APIReference/API_GenerateDataKey.html

```
We recommend that you use the following pattern to encrypt data locally in your application:

Use the GenerateDataKey operation to get a data encryption key.

Use the plaintext data key (returned in the Plaintext field of the response) to encrypt data locally, then erase the plaintext data key from memory.
```

Would this code be sufficient to ensure that the plaintext key has been erased from memory when done using it.

```
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const kms = new aws.KMS({...config});

(async () => {

    /** {Plaintext: Buffer, CiphertextBlob: Buffer} **/
    let dataKey = await kms.generateDataKey({...options}).promise();

    let encryptedString = MyEncryptionFunction(dataKey.Plaintext, "Hello World");

    dataKey.Plaintext.fill(0); //overwrite the buffer with zeroes to erase from memory;
})();

function MyEncryptionFunction(key, dataString) {
    let iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
    let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("aes256", key, iv);
    return cipher.update(dataString, "utf8", "hex") + cipher.final("hex");
}
```

Is it safe to assume the aws sdk doesn't leak/copy the key into other parts of the memory, and the same with the `createCipheriv` function of the builtin crypto library and so just overwriting the `Plaintext` buffer with zeroes should sufficiently wipe the key from memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the AWS Encryption SDK for JavaScript does [1].
In fact, if the Encryption SDK provides the features you need,
I would recommend just using that.

The aws-sdk treats this value as sensitive
and creates an isolated Buffer in Node.js[2].
This means that the plaintext key scoped to this function
and as long as it does not share it,
there are no other copies, and no one has access.
(The usual "no bad people have root access to you server" applies)

Tracing the call createCipheriv in node [3]..[4]
it hands a reference of the key to openSSL, not a copy.

[1] https://github.com/aws/aws-encryption-sdk-javascript/blob/master/modules/material-management/src/cryptographic_material.ts#L343

[2] https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/pull/2622/files

[3] https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/crypto.js#L114

[4] https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/node_crypto.cc#L4099

Comment: Cheers. I'm not sure how exactly I can gain access to that `zeroUnencryptedDataKey` method to call it, but I'm guessing if I just zero fill the buffer myself it's basically doing the same thing and it's gone from memory.

Comment: You do not need call the function yourself.  The Encryption SDK will call it whenever it is done with the material.